# Private IP regex not working in Java

Tags: java, regex, ipv4

I have tried to make this example work in Java:
[Private IP Address Identifier in Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814002/private-ip-address-identifier-in-regular-expression)

I want to check if a IP is a private one, except 127.x.x.x

But I'm going to get crazy, What is wrong in this code?:

```
private static final Pattern patternPrivateNotLocal = Pattern.compile("(^10\\.)|(^172\\.1[6-9]\\.)|(^172\\.2[0-9]\\.)|(^172\\.3[0-1]\\.)|(^1‌​92\\.168\\.)");
public static boolean isPrivateAndNotLocalIP(String ip)
{
    return  patternPrivateNotLocal.matcher(ip).matches();
}
```

The method is returning me `false` when `ip = "192.168.122.1"`

Comment: coud could add a `.*` after each closing bracket in your regex to make it work.

Comment: change "matches" to  "find"

Comment: @nafas `patternPrivateNotLocal.matcher(ip).find();` Does not work either

Comment: there are invisible characters between 1 and 92 in your regex

Comment: @zapl A zero-width non-joiner and a zero-width space. What a clever way to stop people blindly copying your code from the internetz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and paste your code to retry it, but to my suprise it didn't work for me, however, I retyped everything and it started working.

can't say for sure but it must be encoding issues.

just try to **"retype"** everything and change `matches()` to `find()`

if you are going to use `matches` method, you have to match the full text for example

`(^10\\.)` should be changed to `(^10\\..*)`

where as `find` method finds the `first token matched` and return true if any available