# Change the behaviour depending on whether you are in local network or not

Tags: bash

I am making bash script like this

```
if [ "if I am in local "]; then
  ssh myuser@192.168.11
else
  ssh myuser@myserver.com
fi
```

How could I get if I am in local or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to test whether `192.168.11` is ping-able:

```
if ping -qc1 192.168.11 >/dev/null; then
  ssh myuser@192.168.11
else
  ssh myuser@myserver.com
fi
```

If `ping` receives a response from `192.168.11`, then it exits with return code 0 (success) and the `then` clause is executed.  If no responses are returned, the `else` clause is executed.

The option `-c1` tells `ping` to only send one packet.  If your local network is unreliable (unlikely), you may need to send more than one packet.

The `-q` option tells `ping` to be a bit more quiet but that doesn't really matter because we dump its output into `/dev/null`.

Note that IP addresses are typically written with 4 values, not 3: a number may be missing from `192.168.11`.

#### Documentation

From `man ping`:

> If  ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with
>   code 1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer
>   than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived,
>   it will  also  exit  with code 1.  On other error it exits with code
>   2. Otherwise it exits with code 0. This makes it possible to use the exit code to see if a host is alive or not.

Answer (score 1):

This works with assumption then IP addresses starting with 10,127,197,172 are reserved IP for private network.

```
myIp=$(hostname -I) # or i based on your version. 
echo $myIp |grep -q -P '(^127\.)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)'

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then
  echo "Private Network"
else
  echo "Over Internet"
fi
```

Inspiration from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814002/private-ip-address-identifier-in-regular-expression) .

Comment: hostname seems not to have '-i' option and hostname returns real just a 'hostname' not ip address

Comment: try `hostname -I` , I in uppercase